# Using Spring RestTemplate in JAX-RS project

Tags: spring, rest, jax-rs

My project consist of 5 modules. And only one of them uses JAX-RS, others use Spring. My current task is develop service, that will be send HTTP requests to some API. I wanna use Spring `RestTemplate` for this task, but problem is project with JAX-RS haven't `RestTemplate` class and other needfull dependencies. I wanna use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

in the JAX-RS module, to avoid code duplicating for `RestTemplate` and for some JAX-RS client. Is it good idea? Will be `RestTemplate` work properly without `spring-core` dependency?

Comment: you can use the spring-jersey integration. After this you can use spring dependencies just like you use in any spring project. <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Try to create RestTemplate object without spring-core. If it is getting created den you don't need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Using RestTemplate

To use [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) you need just the [`spring-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web) dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The [`spring-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web) dependency has [`spring-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core) as a transitive dependency.

To use [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) it's as simple as:

```java
public class ExampleWithRestTemplate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = 
            restTemplate.getForEntity("http://date.jsontest.com", String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

### Considering JAX-RS Client API as an alternative

Instead of [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) you also could consider [JAX-RS 2.0 Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) to consume REST web services. Jersey is the JAX-RS reference implementation and offers a great API.

To use Jersey Client API, the following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html).

You also could consider the [Jersey Client Proxy API](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/proxy/package-summary.html). The basic idea of this approach is to attach the standard JAX-RS annotations to an interface, and then implement that interface by a resource class on the server side while reusing the same interface on the client side by dynamically generating an implementation of that using [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) calling the right low-level client API methods.

To use the Jersey Client Proxy API, the following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my question is not about alternatives to `RestTemplate`, it's about properly work in project without configured `Spring` with `@Configuration`, `@Bean`, `DispatcherServlet` and so on.